# What is the minimal age, at which "Starship troopers" the book is safe for a child?

Tags: books

I want to "hook" my child on reading. I had a partial victory with *Minecraft for Dummies* (he found it useful) and after talking to him I found out that he may be interested in reading [Starship troopers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers) by Robert Heinlein.

At what age is this **book** (not the movie) safe for a child?

By "safe" I mean not too much and not too hard violence, no sex. I'm rereading that book right now to figure it out for myself, but I'd like to hear the opinions of other parents.

I found [age ratings](https://www.commonsensemedia.org/movie-reviews/starship-troopers/user-reviews) for the movie, but not for the book.

Comment: My daughter was 4 when we read The Hobbit and Treasure Island. She was old enough to say Lord of the Rings was too hard to understand. I'd say it depends on the kid. I might wait a few years before letting her in on Stephen King novels.

Comment: Unlike the movie, there is zero sex in the book. And no real glorification of violence or graphic descriptions, although does have that sort of mid-50's rah-rah support of the military that you would expect from John Wayne of the same era.

Comment: I had my son read it around 12-13 years, and I don't see any reason I couldn't have gone a few years younger.  The hurdle is not the sex (there is none) nor the violence (pretty tame), but the discussions about political systems and civic responsibility.  They just wouldn't make sense to a younger child.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with this question is that there is no definitive answer, and just asking for opinions is a) not necessarily going to help you as all opinions could be correct for that individual, and b) not suitable on the Stack Exchange platform.

I may tell you it is fine for an 11 year old, someone else may be happy giving it to their 8 year old, and someone else may consider it offensive for anyone.

Your best route is almost certainly the one you have taken - read the book yourself and decide whether you are happy with your child reading it. And if you have concerns, you could read it with them, or encourage them to come to you to ask about any of the more adult themes or to understand the satire.